# симулятор Xcode неправильно отображает расположение объектов в приложении

Tags: objective-c, xcode, интерфейс, storyboard, xcode7

При запуске симулятора iPhone в Xcode, объекты интерфейса смещаются в право, в сторибоард выставляю всё по центру. Модель телефона одна, что в Xcode, что в симуляторе. Может кто знает как победить это смещение? Версия Xcode 7.3.1

[image: неправильное отображение объектов в симуляторе Xcode7]

Comment: а на телефоне все работает как надо?

Comment: я еще не покупал сертификат разработчика, так что не знаю как будет на реальном телефоне(

Comment: сертификат нужен только чтобы в аппстор загружать

Comment: Max, вы правы, я не внимательно прочитал сообщение Xcode,  спасибо за поправку)

Answer (score 1):

Вы работаете с Size Classes. Она появилась вместе с Xcode 6.

В сториборде выбран абстрактный размер с обозначением
(compact Width | regular Height)
Внизу, можно увидеть сетку выбора конфигурации, для работы с определенным типом устройства (включая ipad).

Именно по этой причине у Вас все смещается в симуляторое (с реальным устройством будет то же самое).

Так что же необходимо сделать:

Добавить Constraints на все объекты интерфейса.
В данном случае TextLabel, TextView, Button.

т.е растянуть элементы относительно абстрактного экрана для того, что бы на всех размерах объекты интерфейса выглядели красиво.

Вот исчерпывающая статья по теме:
https://habrahabr.ru/post/235181/

Comment: Артур, спасибо Вам за ответ и ссылку)) то что надо!